# How to stop the program until the user input EOF?

Tags: c, eof

I've this difficult assignment where I only have to use for loop.. so we're not allowed to use while or do.. while loop also else statement.. am trying to take the user input until he/she input EOF, so that the program will return the average number. So I wrote the code and ran it but whenever I enter ctrl+z (EOF) the program wont stop or even return the average values :(

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

printf("Please enter employee rank: ");
 scanf("%d", &newnum);

    sumavg += newnum;
    counter++;
    avg = sumavg / counter;

    if (newnum < 8) {
        summ += newnum;
        ccoun++;
        avgle = summ / ccoun;
    }

}

printf("the avg : %d", avg);
printf("\nthe avg : %d \n", avgle);
```

So, I updated the code and there is a minor problem here.. idk why the program don't respond from the first time I enter EOF..

```
for (int i = 0; i < BN; i++) {
printf("Please enter employee rank: ");
result = scanf("%d", &newnum);
    if (result == EOF)
        break;

    sumavg += newnum;
    counter++;
    avg = sumavg / counter;

    if (newnum < 8) {
        summ += newnum;
        ccoun++;
        avgle = summ / ccoun;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is **50** just a random number or the size of the array?

Comment: `newnum[i]==EOF` does not make much sense. If the stream reaches its end the value is not scanned by `scanf`

Comment: If you only need to return the average, why do you store all the values in an array? Adding up the sum and dividing by the number is enough.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use `else` you can use a second `if` with the opposite condition. Hint: You can store return values of functions and compare multiple times.

Comment: @alex01011 Yes it's a random value

Comment: @Gerhardh can you please check the question again I updated it

Comment: _ctrl+z_ (the first one) is not certainly an EOF.  Try running code with piped input from a file.  Be clear if after the last number there is a line-feed or not.  Also what shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the return value of `scanf()`. From the `scanf()` [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html),

> ```
>    The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before
>    either the first successful conversion or a matching failure
>    occurs.  EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which
>    case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set,
>    and errno is set to indicate the error.
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int newNum[50];

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        int ret = scanf("%d", &newNum[i]);

        if (ret != 1) /* 1 int to read */ 
        {
            if (ret == EOF)
            {
                /* input error might also have occured here, check errno to be sure */
                break;
            }
        }
        /* code */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or directly in the for loop,

```
for (int i = 0;  i < ARRAY_SIZE && scanf("%d", &newNum[i]) == 1; i++)
{
    /* code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d", &foo)` doesn't store `EOF` in `foo` on end of file. But you are allready checking for `EOF` when doing `scanf`, use that to break your loop.

```
for(....)
 {
    if(scanf(...) != EOF)
      {
         ....
      }
   else
     {
       break;
     }
 }
```

The code above has only a minor problem, it does detect IO errors and end of file, but not parse errors. It would be better to write something like this:

```
for(int i=0; ...)
  {
    int n;
    int err;
    err = scanf("%d", &n);
    if ( err == 1)
      {
        /* Process input */
        newnum[i] = n;
      }
    else if (err == EOF  && ferror(stdin))
      {
        /* IO error */
        perror ("Failure to read from standard input");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    else if (err == EOF)
      break;
    else
      {
        /* Handle parse errors */
      }
  }
```

Naturally you have to fit error handling to your needs.

Answer (score -2):

When I need EOF from stdin I run program as bellow.

```
./a.out <<DATA
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
DATA
```

This works fine on Linux. Not sure how is works on other platform

Comment: How does this answer the question? The input is not handled correctly, no matter how you generate it.